# Explanation on Constant Multiple rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$
> \frac{d}{dt} \left[5t^{1/2} \right]
>   = 5 \frac{d}{dt} \left[t^{1/2} \right]
>   = 5 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) t^{-1/2}
> $$

Constant Multiple Rule formula: f prime of (x) = nx^n-1

- step 1: f(t) = 5t^1/2
- step 2: d/dt[5t^1/2]
- step 3: 5 d/dt [t^1/2]
- step 4: 5(1/2)t^1/2

I can't really understand how step 4 was derived. The author seems to be re-applying the constant multiple rule on step 3

5 d/dt [t^1/2] = 5 as the constant, n as 1/2 and t to the power of (1/2 - 1) to derive step 4.

Is my understanding correct?

**Updated as per gt6989b's explanation**

Constant Multiple Rule: If you take the derivative of a constant times a function, multiple the constant by the derivative of the function.

Step 1: Apply the "Constant Multiple Rule"
derivative of a constant times a function = d/dt[5t^1/2]

to

multiple the constant by the derivative of the function = 5 * d/dt[t^1/2]

Step 2: apply the "Power Rule"

5 * d/dt[t^1/2] = nx^n-1

to

5(1/2)t^(1/2-1) -> 5(1/2)t^(-1/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left[5t^{1/2} \right] = 5 \frac{d}{dt} \left[t^{1/2} \right]
$$
because derivative is a linear operation and hence constants factor in and out of the derivative sign at will, e.g. $(af(x))' = af'(x)$.

The next step involves the power rule, that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[x^n\right] = nx^{n-1} \quad \text{for } n \ne 1
$$
which in your case yields
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left[t^{1/2} \right] = \frac{1}{2} t^{-1/2}
$$

Comment: Am i right to break down the equation into 2 steps, first apply the constant multiple rule, second, apply the power rule.

Comment: In my case, it should yield 5/2 * t^-1/2 right?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything You are correct.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything yes, correct on both counts